# In Linear Algebra, why is a pivot called a pivot?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

In Linear Algebra, why is a pivot called a pivot?

I have the vague idea that in a system of equations each column is ( at least initially, conceptually ) a free variable. Then, as we gain information about the values in a matrix, the domain of those variables becomes limited, bound--inasmuch as we hope to find a consistent solution to the system of equations.

Furthermore, as the domain of these columns become determined, we find that the solution space of our system of equations is progressively less free to "pivot" inside the boundaries established by bounds of the information we know.

Does any of this ( imprecisely worded ) paragraph make sense? Does it at all show that I am beginning to understand the etymology of the term "pivot" in the context of Linear Algebra?

Comment: Think about Gaussian elimination - you want to knock out certain entries using one as a fulcrum.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but in my linear algebra course, adding a multiple of one row to another is called pivoting. As a result, I thought it's called a pivot because you can add it to other rows while keeping it the same, kind of like you're free to change stuff as long as you keep the pivot fixed.

Comment: Personally I don't like this terminology. Where does it come from ? Someone once must have put in a textbook.

Comment: Pivot: 1 [...] 2. Something or someone having a paramount significance in a certain situation. (From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pivot))

Comment: As the above comment mentions you could think of these entries/rows as pivotal to solving the system